# Common JSON schema in Java server side and Angular app

Tags: java, json, angular

I have a Java server side and Angular app. They communicate by JSON object. I want them to have common JSON schema.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how we do it,

1. Create a schema JSON file,
2. Create an API which will be used to send you the same if called,
3. Configure your angular application with APP_Initialize in your module.ts and then use the same schema in your client as well.

That way you will always have same schema file for your front end and backend.

Comment: I guess it is for both the front end and the backend.

Comment: JSON Schema in a Java-Backend ?  i assume you would need an extra library for this.

Comment: which extra library?